# Laravel collection using where is only working locally, not on the server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5 collections. My query is as follows;

```
$lastplace = collect(@$this->places)->where('type', 'street')->last();
```

Locally it will return the correct last item in the array but on the server it will return null with an exact replica of the DB on both local+server.

I'm running the MySQL Native Driver and I don't have issues with any other queries, just this one on the server.

Out of ideas..

Comment: Why are you writng `@this`?

Comment: @mazedlx thanks for the question, I'm writing it to get the current place that's returned from the controller.

Comment: No, what I meant was why are you supressing warnings from `$this? with the @ sign in front?

Comment: I shouldn't be :D just habit I guess. But it still doesn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: :-) Be that as it may, DON'T DO THAT!

Comment: @mazedlx Thanks for the heads up, I'll definitely be more cautious next time. Any idea why this query is working locally and not on the server though?

Comment: The DB is an exact replica, but is the Laravel Framework?

Comment: Exact replica of the codebase on both. I do a git deploy so it's identical in every way, shape and form.

Comment: Did you try a `dd(collect($this->places))`without the additional parameters?

Comment: `Laravel Framework version 5.2.43` on both just so you're aware :) I'll give that a try now.

Comment: `Collection places: [{"...."}]`

Comment: So this means that `$this->places` doesn't yield any results. It seems that you don't store anything to this variable. Could you try retrieving this places data via an Eloquent Model?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, it returned a lot of data I just didn't want to paste it here in comments as it would be unstructured. But it's returning data fine.

Comment: So, you get data on both environments? That's good. Next step: add the `->where('type', 'street')` to the `collect($this->places)`and `dd()`.

Comment: `Collection places: []` now it's empty. The data definitely has type "street" for many of them so for some reason the `where()` isn't working but only on the server.

Comment: Could you show me a few lines of the `dd()` output?

Comment: Is PHP version the same on both environments?

Comment: Ahhh you're a legend. So for some reason the data is outputting integers as strings so `"place_type":"0"` instead of `"place_type":0` so when I look for that particular one. Type street was actually fine, it was the place_type that caused the issue :)

Comment: @BrunoFernandes Yup, both on 5.5.9 as well. Thanks though.

Comment: @mazedlx for your help I would love to accept your debugging as the answer that lead me to the actual answer. Without your clear headed thinking I wouldn't have managed to find the issue. Thanks again

Comment: @DT.DTDG added my comments as answer, thanks for the vote

Answer (score 0):

just 2 cents.

If DB is same, code is same then it has to do with server settings, verify log to get some pointers. make sure that required PHP extensions are enabled like mcrypt.

Comment: thanks, but mcrypt has nothing to do with it - the module is installed irrespective otherwise Laravel wouldn't work.

Comment: do you get count?

Comment: Sorry? I received items in the returned JSON if that's what you mean. Fixed with a separate issue where integers were converting to strings. MySQLnd was installed but required a reboot of the server for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the output step by step:

1. Step

   `dd($this->places);`
2. Step

   `dd($this->places->where('type', 'street'));`

Always compare the output on both systems